# Apollo Client: What is the counterpart of the Redux Toolkit "transformResponse()" in Apollo Client?

Tags: graphql, apollo-client, redux-toolkit

In Apollo Client, I would like to transform the responses from a GraphQL query with a customized method `transformResponse()` before it hits the cache.

In Redux Toolkit (RTK), this functionality is available, which is called `transformResponse()` (https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/customizing-queries#customizing-query-responses-with-transformresponse).

So the question: does the counterpart of `transformResponse()` in RTK exist in Apollo Client? Whether the answer is yes or no, what is the proper way to perform such an action?

[image: Diagram]

Comment: Hi, creator of RTK Query and maintainer of Apollo Client here :) As Apollo Client is a normalized GraphQL cache and works very differently from RTK Query: Could you please explain what you want to use it for?

Comment: @phry Hi, thank you for picking up the question. In general: The response we are now obtaining from the GraphQL query is not exactly what we want. We want to transform it so that it conforms with a predefined interface (with, for example, calculated properties and additional fields). In another project where RTK query is used, I know that can be achieved by `transformResponse()`. However as a newbie to Apollo Client I realized that this becomes different, and want to know how to do that properly.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you can't do that with Apollo Client, as that really mimics the structure of your query.
You could have the query contain fragments, though, and use the experimental (as of AC 3.7) `useFragment` hook to directly access those fragments from your components (while a parent component fetched the query). That's probably the closest you will get.

For everything else, you would have to create a custom hook that does this transformation in a `useMemo` hook call.

Comment: Just a short update: we decided to perform `transformResponse()` after the caching procedure. In this way, we first pass the response to a lower level component, then in that component we perform the response transformation, and finally display it to the user.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can try [`afterware`](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/v2/networking/network-layer/#afterware) to modify the response.

Here is the detailed thread in the same issue:
https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/2534